# my question is about binary search implementation

Tags: python, binary-search

I am a new python programmer who knows about the binary search algorithm, and tries to make a python implementation of it.
my code is:

```
def binsearch(a, t) :
    length = len(a)
    if length == 1 and a[0] == t:
        return True
    elif t > a[length-1] or t < a[0]:
        return False
    else:
        d = int(length/2)
        if t == a[d-1]:
            return True
        elif t < a[d-1]:
            g = a[:d]
            binsearch(g, t)
        else:
            g = a[:d]
            binsearch(g, t)
f = [x for x in range(100)]
print(binsearch(f, 24))
```

when i run the function with a=[x for x in range(100)] and t=24, it returns None.
please let me know the reason.

Comment: you are only calling function instead of returning it.

Comment: `return binsearch(g, t)` - you need to pass the result back out

Comment: in python, when a function doesn't return something, it returns None by default

Comment: also your elif and else block has same statement and affect

Comment: What is the difference between line 12 and 15. Try to call `return binsearch(g,t)` instead of only call `binsearch(g,t)`

Answer (score 0):

Firs problem is that you are just calling `binsearch()` when you're splitting your array instead of returning it. Second problem is that if `t` is for example `> 50` you will initiate `g` to first half of your array instead do `g = a[d:]` on second condition block.

```
def binsearch(a, t):
    length = len(a)
    if length == 1 and a[0] == t:
        return True
    elif t > a[length-1] or t < a[0]:
        return False
    else:
        d = int(length/2)
        if t == a[d-1]:
            return True
        elif t < a[d-1]:
            g = a[:d]
            return binsearch(g, t)
        else:
            g = a[d:]
            return binsearch(g, t)
f = [x for x in range(100)]

print(binsearch(f, 24)) # -> True
print(binsearch(f, 66)) # -> True
print(binsearch(f, 100)) # -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other programming languages, you must return a value explicitly from functions. In your code you need to write:

```
return binsearch(g, t)
```

To understand it, let’s say your code recurs 3 times, the return value will look something like:

```
|  # starts with 1st recursion into 2nd
return binsearch(g, t):
|  # into 3rd
return (return binsearch(g, t))
```

Now the innermost one produces its value:

```
return True
```

And it gets passed down the recursion chain:

```
return (return (return True))
|  # evaluate 3rd recursion
return (return True)
|  # evaluate 2nd recursion 
return True
# evaluate 1st recursion
```